# Java application consuming native memory dependent on number of CPUs

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, memory-leaks, kubernetes

I have a dockerized Java Application running in a Kubernetes cluster. Till now I have had configured a CPU limit of 1.5 cores. Now I increased the available CPUs to 3 to make my app perform better.

Unfortunately it needs significantly more Memory now and gets OOMKilled by Kubernetes. This graph shows a direct comparison of the overall memory consumption of the container for 1.5 cores (green) and 3 cores (yellow) (nothing different but the CPU limits):

[image: Grafana Comparison]

The Java Heap is always looking good and seems not to be a problem. The memory consumption is in the native memory.

My application is implemented with Spring Boot 1.5.15.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.2.17.FINAL, Flyway, Tomcat. I compile with Java 8 and start it with a Docker OpenJDK 10 container.

I debugged a lot the last days using JProfiler and jmealloc as described in [this post about native memory leak detection](https://gdstechnology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/). JMEalloc told me about a large amount of Java.util.zipInflater.

Has anyone any clue what could explain the (for me very irrational) coupling of available CPUs to native memory consumption? 
Any hints would be appreciated :-)!

Thanks & Regards

Matthias

Comment: I can't think of anything in Spring Boot that would link native memory usage to the number of available CPUs. However, please be aware that Spring Boot 1.5 does not support Java 10. The latest version of Java support by Boot 1.5 is Java 8. It's also worth noting that Java 10 is no longer supported. If you want to use a version of Java beyond 8, I would recommend using Java 11 with Spring Boot 2.1.

Comment: As far i remember, if you dont set the springboot memory, he uses de JVM limit.
Your graph is basic the java using all free memory in Eden Space, when get full, GC come and free the memory.
I would recommend to set the memory limits and let the JVM deal with.